# How to read cookies in getStaticProps and getStaticPaths in Next.js

Tags: cookies, next.js

I cannot read cookies in `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps`, in SSR, I can request the cookie with context but even with packages such as `js-cookie, cookie-cutter, cookies`, I am unable to read the cookies set, which makes it impossible to get the data.

[image: Cookie]

This is the token I want to get, I removed `httpOnly` for development.

```
export async function getStaticPaths(){
    const data = await callApi("/jobs", "GET", token)

    const paths = data.map(jobs => ({
        params: {slug: jobs.slug}
    }))
    return{
        paths,
        fallback: true,
    }
}
```

This is the getStaticPaths.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

both `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` are methods that run on the server (node.js), therefore cookies which is a browser API are not available yet

Comment: Is there a way to pass data from the ```default component like default home()``` to the getStaticPaths or getStaticProps?

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11916 check this discussion, might be helpful

Comment: @Mazino Note that running on the server isn't the actual reason why you can't access cookies in `getStaticProps` - it is because `getStaticProps` only runs at build time, and has no access to request-specific data. `getServerSideProps` also runs on the server, but because it runs on every request it does have access to cookies through the request headers.

Comment: @juliomalves didn't actually know this, but it does makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 6):

Cookies can be accessed both on the server `req.cookies` or `req.headers.cookie` and on the client `document.cookie`. But unlike `getServerSideProps` where the HTML is generated at runtime, `getStaticProps` generates the HTML at build time and therefore has no know knowledge of requesting devise/browser. This is evident from how user-agent looks when the request is sent from `getStaticProps`:

```
'user-agent': 'node-fetch/1.0 (+https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch)'
```

Also, there's a demo app [here](https://static-next-willemliu.vercel.app/) showing how this all works.

If your reason for trying to access cookies from `getStaticProps` is for authentication, have a look at this post on [The way they built the zeit.co/vercel dashboard (fully static)](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10724#discussioncomment-720)

Also [here](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper#getstaticprops), using [next-redux-wrapper](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper) to access state from `getStaticProps`.

Comment: the response time from getServerSideProps for cookies is very slow is there a away to speed this up ?

Comment: Try [JWT Authentication with Middleware](https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/edge-functions/jwt-authentication). also have a look at [Next.js 12.2 Blog](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12-2?utm_source=next-site&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=next-website)

Answer (score 0):

if you have placed your cookies and want to read them you can get them in `getServerSideProps` *ctx.req.cookies* here your cookies

here is the link so you shouldn't try getting cookies in getStaticProps
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11734#discussioncomment-3993