# Is it possible to pass details stored in localStorage or Cookies to getStaticPaths and getStaticProps in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Is it possible to pass information stored from localStorage or Cookies to getStaticPaths and getStaticProps in next, the API that holds the data of the content I need, needs me to pass in the current logged-in user's id to be able to fetch the data I want

Comment: It's not possible, either you move the API request to the client-side or use `getServerSideProps` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read cookies in getStaticProps and getStaticPaths in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66372274/how-to-read-cookies-in-getstaticprops-and-getstaticpaths-in-next-js)

Answer (score 0):

getStatisPaths and getStaticProps is run at build time. You cant use cookies. You can use getServerSideProps.

Provided `req` middleware in getServerSideProps -

The `req` in the context passed to `getServerSideProps` provides built in middleware that parses the incoming request (req). That middleware is:

```
`req.cookies` - An object containing the cookies sent by the request. Defaults to `{}`
```