# Access cookies on the "server" with a statically generated Next.js site?

Tags: cookies, next.js

I have created a statically generated website with Next.js, using `getStaticProps()`. On the website there is a button where you can switch between three different themes (lower right in the picture).

[image]

This works as excepted, but now I would like to persist this between each session, and apply correct theme when the page is loaded. I know I can do this client side, but this will cause the website to always flash from white to the selected color, which is not good.

Is there any way to solve this? I don't want to convert the website to server rendered, just to enable this feature. Maybe something with edge workers, the new middleware etc? I have no idea.

Comment: If you want to access cookies in Next.js middleware I'd recommend a read through: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware#using-cookies.

Comment: I've seen that page, but how can I go from that to render different page backgrounds? Without redirecting to three different pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Hennessy811 had a great suggestion:

> You can manage background on client side via custom _document.tsx before content load to prevent content flash

I'm expanding upon that answer here, for others to see, as this was the best solution for my problem.

```
import Script from "next/script";
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html lang="en" className="">
      <Head>
        <Script id="theme" strategy="beforeInteractive">
          {`
          const html = document.querySelector("html");
          if (document.cookie === "theme=theme-black") {
            html.classList.remove("theme-white");
            html.classList.remove("theme-peach");
            html.classList.add("theme-black");
          } else if (document.cookie === "theme=theme-peach") {
            html.classList.remove("theme-black");
            html.classList.remove("theme-white");
            html.classList.add("theme-peach");
          } else {
            html.classList.remove("theme-black");
            html.classList.remove("theme-peach");
            html.classList.add("theme-white");
            }
          `}
        </Script>
      </Head>
      <body className="">
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

It's important to use the `strategy="beforeInteractive"` (this only works in `_document.tsx`), so that we can add the class before anything is actually rendered, to prevent the content flash.

Answer (score 2):

If you need this kind of logic, `getStaticProps` and static generation probably is not the best option. As mentioned above, you can pre-generate page for all themes and redirect between them based on cookies, but probably its not what is going to work well.

Another option here - is to render background on client side (its just a background, right), and its not worth pre-rendering several pages for that.
(+ we can easily imagine how complex it may become if you would like to add i18n, for example, you'll need to render each page quite much :))

You can manage background on client side via custom _document.tsx before content load to prevent content flash (like daisy ui does with tailwind, for example - they provide 20+ themes and they work pretty good)

Otherwise, you can prerender using `getServerSideProps`, I think its quite obvious way

Personally, I'd prefer client way, it should not be tricky to implement

Comment: Thanks for describing different options. :) You mention: "You can manage background on client side via custom _document.tsx before content load to prevent content flash"
How can I dod this? I can't use `useEffect` for instance, in `_document.tsx`.

Comment: Figured it out, and expanded upon this in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it cannot be done, and asked already here:

[How to read cookies in getStaticProps and getStaticPaths in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66372274/how-to-read-cookies-in-getstaticprops-and-getstaticpaths-in-next-js)

getStaticProps is at build time, so there is no notion of cookie.

***However :)***

I'm thinking maybe there is a hack you can use. Haven't tried it, but should work:

You could use Next.js [redirects](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects) (or [rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites)) [based on the cookie value](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects#header-cookie-and-query-matching), to redirect to a pre-built page in one of the 3 themes.

So if you detect "theme=blue" in the cookie, you could rewrite the page as /blueIndex.js:

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
        {
        source: '/',
        has: [
          {
            type: 'cookie',
            key: 'theme',
            value: 'blue',
          },
        ],
        permanent: true,
        destination: '/blueIndex.js',
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

Answer (score -2):

> You could use Next.js redirects (or rewrites) based on the cookie value, to redirect to a pre-built page in one of the 3 themes. So if you detect "theme=blue" in the cookie, you could rewrite the page as /blueIndex.js:

Actually, that's a great hack.  However, I think browser and/or device [fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint) would be easier.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).